# Avoid project's directory - Java EE app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am writing and small app using Java EE. I am using Apache Tomcat v 7 and Eclipse as IDE. When I Run the project (Run on server) I get :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/java-web/lis
```

(That's fine)

But I don't know If there is some way to rewrite  the [java-web] dir just to get :

```
http://my-local-app.dev/list
```

I suppose there is some way like in Apache Server using confing files and enabling 
the mod_rewrite.

I'll apreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: is your actual url is http://127.0.0.1:8080/java-web/lis or http://127.0.0.1:8080/java-web/list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: All of the pieces you want to change are components of your deployment environment. Unless you have a specific need to override them, it's usually easiest during development to use the URLs that are a little less pretty.

If you do want to alter them, you need to familiarize yourself with what the various parts of an HTTP URL mean. What you have in your test environment is this:

```
http://  127.0.0.1:8080/java-web/list
protocol host      port path
```

You could insert an entry into your `hosts` file listing `my-local-app.dev` at `127.0.0.1`, but that would not change the port or the path.

The port is determined when Tomcat starts up and is 8080 by default. The general port for HTTP is 80, but specific permission is required to bind to ports below 1024. On Linux, the `authbind` package makes this pretty easy; on Windows, the necessary steps will depend on your version and configuration (e.g., if you have a Group Policy).

In Tomcat, Web applications are prefixed with their names in the path; it looks like your (hypothetical?) application is named `java-web.war`. You can install an application as the "root application", but this requires a little bit more configuration and is generally skipped in development.

All of this can indeed also be done using something like `mod_rewrite`, but that seems like overkill to have slightly prettier URLs for your dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your application to respond to the my-local-app.dev, you need to purchase the "my-local-app.dev" domain and get a Java web hotel running on it.

If your web application is named "java-web" and you do not want the URL to reflect that, you need to tell Tomcat that you want your application deployed at the ROOT location where the name of the web application is not present in the URL.  This is typically done in the deployment stage but unfortunately there is no standard location to say this for WAR files so this is vendor dependent.  For example does Glassfish use an extra XML file in your deployment.

I believe Tomcat supports this for ROOT.war files.  If not, you probably needs to set the META-INF/context.xml file.  See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html for details on what to put in this file - especially the context path.

Comment: @chrylis my way of putting that the server behind the IP corresponding to the DNS name should be able to have java applications deployed to it.

Comment: Do you mean a servlet container?

Comment: Or a full application server... For instance.